# Is this algorithm correct in finding the range of a function?

Tags: calculus

suppose I'm given that the domain of $f$ which lies in $[a,b]$ or $(a,b)$. And I'm asked to find the range.

Here's what I have thought about finding the range of f:
mark the critical points by find f', and let this be in the set of values named A.

And compute the functions value for the points which is leading to a discontinuity, by taking the limit, let this be in a set of values named S.

Now I can plug in the points from A into f, and also f(a) and f(b), and compare all of them with set S to find the global maxima and minima,

Can I conclude that the function will output values from the set $(g_{min},g_{max})$ by intermediate value property, and hence the function's range is that?

Comment: For definiteness, let's say we're speaking of a real-valued function $f$ defined on a closed, bounded interval $[a, b]$ that is differentiable except possibly for finitely many jump discontinuities and corners (where the derivative jumps). Generally 1. The image might contain one or both endpoints $f_{\min}$ and $f_{\max}$. Particularly, if $f$ is continuous, the image is a closed, bounded interval by the extreme value theorem. 2. The image might not be an interval, due to jump discontinuities. <> Still, you've got a good start on a procedure!